# Dump entire ELF binary into readable headers and sections

Tags: binary, analysis, dump, elf

Is it possible to dump an entire binary structure of an ELF-ARM file into a readable format.The idea is to analyze each section and save it back to a binary.

Comment: By "save it back to binary" do you mean that you want to modify the binary through the human readable format?

Answer (score 5):

There are several tools for inspecting the inner structures of elf files, the most common are readelf, objdump and elfsh (from the ERESI framework). It depends on what part of the binary are you interested in, but, for example, you can dump the section header table using the following command:

```
arm-elf-objdump -h elffile
```

If you want to copy a certain section from the elf file into a raw binary file, use objcopy:

```
arm-elf-objcopy -j .data -O binary elffile binfile
```

Comment: hey Jah ... Thanks for the reply.What I was looking for is a tool similar to IDA but command line that is capable of returning the 'text' view(not binary content) of the elf binary.Like....                                                             `.text:080486A0                 mov     eax, [edx]
         .text:080486A2                 add     edx, 4
         .text:080486A5                 test    eax, eax`     Thanks SrK

Comment: you can use objdump -d for that